# Cannot link object files because of undefined reference

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, header, compilation

I cannot link object files. Compilation works fine, but the linker gives me these error messages:

> testArguments.o: In function `Z6__mainiPPc':
>   /cygdrive/c/Users/Lukas/work/ProxyServer/src/test/testArguments.cpp:5:
>   undefined reference to`Arguments::Arguments()'
>   /cygdrive/c/Users/Lukas/work/ProxyServer/src/test/testArguments.cpp:6:
>   undefined reference to `Arguments<int>::insertItem(int)'
>   /cygdrive/c/Users/Lukas/work/ProxyServer/src/test/testArguments.cpp:8:
>   undefined reference to`_Unwind_Resume' testArguments.o: In function
>   `ZNSt10_List_baseIiSaIiEED2Ev':
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/bits/stl_list.h:378:
>   undefined reference to`_Unwind_Resume' testArguments.o: In function
>   `ZN9__gnu_cxx13new_allocatorISt10_List_nodeIiEE10deallocateEPS2_j':
>   /usr/lib/gcc/i686-pc-cygwin/4.8.2/include/c++/ext/new_allocator.h:110:
>   undefined reference to`operator delete(void*)'
>   testArguments.o:testArguments.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined
>   reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
>   testArguments.o:testArguments.cpp:(.eh_frame$_ZNSt10_List_baseIiSaIiEED2Ev+0x13):
>   undefined reference to`__gxx_personality_v0' Makefile:7: recipe for
>   target 'tests' failed

But these functions are defined in the cpp file (Argument::Arguments() Arguments::insertItem(int)

Here is my header file:

```
#ifndef ARGUMENTS_H 

#define ARGUMENTS_H

#include <list>


using std::list;
template<class T>
class Arguments{

public:

        Arguments(list<T> args);>

    Arguments()>;

    void insert>Item(T item);

    list<T> getValues();

private:

    list<T> values;
};
#endif
```

Here the cpp file:

```
#include "include/Arguments.h"
#include <list>
using std::list;

template<class T> Arguments<T>::Arguments(list<T> args) {

    values = args;

}

template<class T> Arguments<T>::Arguments() {

}

template<class T> void Arguments<T>::insertItem(T argument){
    values.push_back(argument); 
}

template<class T> list<T> Arguments<T>::getValues() {
    return this.values;

}
```

Comment: Your header file won't even compile. `#include ` & more...

Comment: @DietmarKühl Do we have a FAQ entry for this kind of thing?

Comment: @pmr: I'm currently using a mobile device and can't access the description page for the C++ tag but I think it has a small FAQ listing this issue.